# Maintain a counter while looping a query result set

Tags: php, while-loop, counter, increment, resultset

I have the following:

```
$counter = 1;   
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $counter2 = $counter++;
    echo $counter2 . $row['foo'];
}
```

Is there an easier way to get 1,2,3 etc for each result or is this the best way?

Comment: Why aren't you just using the `$counter` variable?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You don't need $counter2.  $counter++ is fine.  You can even do it on the same line as the echo if you use preincrement instead of postincrement.

```
$counter = 0;   
while($row= mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo(++$counter . $row['foo']);
}
```

Comment: Why did you get an upvote? You didn't show him his first error ($counter=2)?

Comment: He was postincrementing $counter, so $counter2 would get the value of $counter before it gets incremented.  This version is using preincrementing, so $counter would get the value 1 before it's echoed for the first time.

Answer (score 17):

I know it's not exactly what you have asked for - but why don't you simply use a for-loop instead of while?

```
for ($i = 0; $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); ++$i) {
    echo $i . $row['foo'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a long time:

- the `mysql` API has been obsolete and
- the `mysqli` API's result set object has been traversable via `foreach()` as if an array of associative rows.

Instead of maintaining the counter manually, just access the index that the `foreach()` provides.

Code: ([Demo](https://phpize.online/s/ip))

```
$sql = <<<SQL
SELECT *
FROM your_table
ORDER BY lastname, firstname
SQL;

foreach ($mysqli->query($sql) as $i => $row) {
    printf(
        "<div>%d: %d, %s, %s</div>\n",
        $i + 1,
        $row['id'],
        $row['firstname'],
        $row['lastname']
    );
}
```