# Automatically Upload CSV file to Database from a specified folder .

Tags: php, mysql, csv, database-connection

Is it possible to upload data from CSV file to my database AUTOMATICALLY ? I am making a PHP project , in which It is needed the database to get updated from a specified path folder . Kindly help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be archived with plain SQL on the server.
Take a look at LOAD DATA INFILE Statement: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/test.txt' INTO TABLE test
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes its easy to implement. you have to create one `PHP` script.

1. get all the files from specific folder using `scandir`
2. parse csv files using `fgetcsv`
3. write database connection code and insert query to insert csv records.
4. set PHP script in Cron Scheduler which would take your CSV entries, format into INSERT SQL statements and fire the query.

Useful links:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php

[How to parse a CSV file using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9139202/how-to-parse-a-csv-file-using-php)

http://coyotelab.org/php/upload-csv-and-insert-into-database-using-phpmysql.html