# Looping through all csv files in a directory, pulling info from each and putting data in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, database, csv, insert

I am trying to write a php script that will read all columns from a directory full of 1000 csv files (all of these files have like columns) and take all the data that it gets from the csv files and then insert it into a mysql database. I have tried writing this 3 different ways after going through tutorials online but I just cannot get it to work.

I am new to PHP so I have no idea what is going on. Is there an easy way to loop through a directory full of 1000 csv files, read in all the data from the files, and then insert the data into a mysql database?

Answer (score 0):

Here is parser [How to parse a CSV file using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9139202/how-to-parse-a-csv-file-using-php) instead of echo you should push to array data, that after fetching to insert bulk into database. Also additionaly you have iterate through all your 1000 files. http://www.php-dev-zone.com/2013/05/how-to-import-csv-file-data-into-mysql.html something like that