# PHP - Getting data from large CSV files

Tags: php, csv

I have a CSV file with about 5000 lines of data that looks like this:

```
color,director_name,num_critic_for_reviews,duration,director_facebook_likes,actor_3_facebook_likes,actor_2_name,actor_1_facebook_likes,gross,genres,actor_1_name,movie_title,num_voted_users,cast_total_facebook_likes,actor_3_name,facenumber_in_poster,plot_keywords,movie_imdb_link,num_user_for_reviews,language,country,content_rating,budget,title_year,actor_2_facebook_likes,imdb_score,aspect_ratio,movie_facebook_likes
Color,James Cameron,723,178,0,855,Joel David Moore,1000,760505847,Action|Adventure|Fantasy|Sci-Fi,CCH Pounder,Avatar ,886204,4834,Wes Studi,0,avatar|future|marine|native|paraplegic,http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0499549/?ref_=fn_tt_tt_1,3054,English,USA,PG-13,237000000,2009,936,7.9,1.78,33000
Color,Gore Verbinski,302,169,563,1000,Orlando Bloom,40000,309404152,Action|Adventure|Fantasy,Johnny Depp,Pirates of the Caribbean: At World's End ,471220,48350,Jack Davenport,0,goddess|marriage ceremony|marriage proposal|pirate|singapore,http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0449088/?ref_=fn_tt_tt_1,1238,English,USA,PG-13,300000000,2007,5000,7.1,2.35,0
Color,Sam Mendes,602,148,0,161,Rory Kinnear,11000,200074175,Action|Adventure|Thriller,Christoph Waltz,Spectre ,275868,11700,Stephanie Sigman,1,bomb|espionage|sequel|spy|terrorist,http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2379713/?ref_=fn_tt_tt_1,994,English,UK,PG-13,245000000,2015,393,6.8,2.35,85000
Color,Christopher Nolan,813,164,22000,23000,Christian Bale,27000,448130642,Action|Thriller,Tom Hardy,The Dark Knight Rises ,1144337,106759,Joseph Gordon-Levitt,0,deception|imprisonment|lawlessness|police officer|terrorist plot,http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1345836/?ref_=fn_tt_tt_1,2701,English,USA,PG-13,250000000,2012,23000,8.5,2.35,164000
,Doug Walker,,,131,,Rob Walker,131,,Documentary,Doug Walker,Star Wars: Episode VII - The Force Awakens             ,8,143,,0,,http://www.imdb.com/title/tt5289954/?ref_=fn_tt_tt_1,,,,,,,12,7.1,,0
Color,Andrew Stanton,462,132,475,530,Samantha Morton,640,73058679,Action|Adventure|Sci-Fi,Daryl Sabara,John Carter ,212204,1873,Polly Walker,1,alien|american civil war|male nipple|mars|princess,http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0401729/?ref_=fn_tt_tt_1,738,English,USA,PG-13,263700000,2012,632,6.6,2.35,24000
```

How can i get certain data, say i need to return just the 5000 "movie_title" items, how could i do this?

**Edit**

The answer i accepted seems to work well, in my case i use this to get the movie title:

```
echo fgetcsv($file)[11] . "\n";
```

and since i had time out errors i added:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
```

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9139202/how-to-parse-a-csv-file-using-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$file = fopen("filename.csv","r");

$limit = 500;    // here specify your line count
$count = 0;
while(! feof($file))
{
    $count++;
    if($count <= $limit)
    {
        print_r(fgetcsv($file));
    }
}

fclose($file);
```

Comment: Perfect this is just what i needed, though it seems very slow but i guess the script must be looking through a high amount of , characters etc.