# Parse CSV file which contains a new line to php array

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I have a CSV file with:

```
Test1,One line
Test2,"Two lines

Hello"
Test3,One line
```

As you can see, one of the columns has a value which is separated with a new line.

To parse this CSV file into an array, I run:

```
$csvArray = array();
$csvData = file_get_contents('file.csv');
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $csvData);
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $csvArray[] = str_getcsv($line);
}
// print_r($csvArray);
```

It works beside one problem. It reads the new line in the value as a **new row**, which is completely incorrect.

How do I make it so that it properly reads a multi-line value?

Edit: this question focuses on new lines.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse a CSV file using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9139202/how-to-parse-a-csv-file-using-php)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
$fp = fopen('filecsv', 'r');

$csvArray = array();

while ($row = fgetcsv($fp)) {
    $csvArray[] = $row;
}

fclose($fp);
```

Using `explode(PHP_EOL, $csvData)` will not correctly split the CSV by its row delimitor.  The multi line cell is encapsulated with quotations meaning the row will continue onto new lines until they are closed.

PHP's built in [`fgetcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) function will correctly read a single row from a file, moving the pointer to the next row in the process. While `str_getcsv` will only read a single row from a string without considering additional rows (because its a string, not a stream).

Since you have already split the string with `explode`, your CSV row is broken, so the row will be incomplete.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your answer?

Comment: Fantastic, thank you very much for this. You are totally correct!