# PhP - When Parsing CSV negative numbers have parenthesis

Tags: php, csv

I am parsing CSV's and I am having no problem reading the CSVs. The only problem is if the CSV has a negative number ex: `-154.64` keeps coming back without the `-` and it's putting parenthesis around it: `(154.64)`.

I need the correct way to turn this parenthesis number back into a negative number. I am inserting these numbers into my DB and if I try and put the `(154.64)` it just puts a positive number in the DB `154.64`.

Thanks!

EDIT

Using [Parse CSV](https://github.com/parsecsv/parsecsv-for-php)

```
$csv = new parseCSV($_FILES['csvUpload']['tmp_name']);

foreach( $csv->data as $row ) :
print_r($row);
endforeach;
```

If there is a negative number it will show:

```
array (
  margin => (123.65)
)
```

I Need

```
array (
  margin => -123.65
)
```

Comment: Please post an excerpt from the csv file you are using and the code you are using to parse it.

Comment: Try using PHP's built in csv functions. [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) should be of particular interest to you. Examples are also provided on that link.

Comment: PHP has built-in support for CSV. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9139202/how-to-parse-a-csv-file-using-php) for more details...