# WordPress - import email subscriptions from *.csv file

Tags: wordpress, subscription, jetpack

How do we import email addresses for `Jetpack subscriptions` into `WP` from `CSV` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have found the answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/56300/how-do-i-import-email-addresses-into-wordpress-com-subscriptions) and joined it with another answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9139202/how-to-parse-a-csv-file-using-php):

`Jetpack subscriptions` are not hosted on your site, they're hosted on the `WordPress.com` servers. So you can't add directly to the database.

However, if you take a look at the Jetpack plugin code, it outlines the `XML-RPC` calls used to interface with `WordPress.com` and add subscribers. So you could build your own importer ...

```
<?php
//1. the "file_name_here.csv" should get changed to your need
//2. the script just needs to get placed on site like "example.com/subscribe.php"
//3. just execute it in the browser using your link

require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php');

$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("file_name_here.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
  while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $num = count($data);
    echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
    $row++;
    for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
        $email = $data[$c];
        echo $email . "<br />\n";
        Jetpack_Subscriptions::subscribe( $email );
    }
  }
  fclose($handle);
}
```