# PHP Split string by character but omit the last occurrence of that character

Tags: php, regex

I have this little problem where i'm getting the content of a CSV using PHP, which works just fine, but then i try to split it using `preg_split` like this:

```
$csv = file_get_contents($file);
$content= preg_split('/\r\n|\r|\n/', $csv);
```

It does split the content but it also adds an empty array key at the end of the array(cause of that new line) so the array will basicly look like this:

```
array(
    [0] => some;content;here;
    [1] => some;other;content;
    [3] => 
)
```

Basicaly my question is: how do i write that regular expression to avoid splitting the last occurrence of that pattern?(and also afterwords i want to split those `array keys` by `;` and again i get an empty `array key` cause there is a `;` at the end of every `string`

Thank you for your time! X_X

Comment: [Trim](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.trim.php) the string before splitting. `preg_split('/\R/', trim($csv))`

Comment: `$content= array_filter( preg_split('/\r\n|\r|\n/', $csv) );` ? to filter empty elements from array. But why not use some of the purpose built methods for dealing with CSV files?

Comment: Is there a reason not to use phps csv-handling functions? (`fgetcsv(...)`)

Comment: Tom and Ram and Wik thanks a lot, the only reason for not using some of csv-handling functions was my limited knowledge :O but nah it's hard in school X_X :D

Comment: Have a read of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9139202/how-to-parse-a-csv-file-using-php

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried fgetcsv(); instead? No need to manually parse the file. http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Comment: oh, well thanks! :D - didn't knew i could do that X_X