# I am getting issues when importing data using .csv into PostgreSQL ( greater than 50K lines in csv)

Tags: php, postgresql

ERROR i'm getting :

> This page isn’t working  didn’t send any data.
>   ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

I am using PHP language for reading the csv file .

My PHP approach is look like for procession the csv data :

```
$csvAsArray = array_map('str_getcsv', file($tmpName));
```

I am sure that the above code creating problem afterwords the code is not getting executing .
How i can import more that greater than at least 1 million data at a time ?
Can anyone help me out , which approach should i choose ?

Comment: Not sure if it's a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9139202/how-to-parse-a-csv-file-using-php but it may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to grab the entire contents of the file in one gulp.  Don't do that :)  PHP [array_map()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_map.asp) isn't scalable to 1000's ... or millions of lines.

SUGGESTION:

1. Read your data into a temp file (as you appear to be doing now).
2. Do a Postgresql [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/sql-copy.html)

EXAMPLE:

```
COPY my_table(my_columns, ...) 
FROM 'my_file.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

Comment: Thanks @paulsm4 for giving the answers .                                                                                        but the problem is that i have to translate all the csv data to DB data for eg . (user_name to user_id  )   if use_name is present in DB (type of foreign key) .                       that what i have to iteration the csv file line by line . So there any other way to do that

Comment: copy into a temporary table.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a [league/csv](https://csv.thephpleague.com/) package for CSV parsing and importing. @paulsm4 is correct that it's never needed to put the whole file into memory and then work with it, one should rather read line-by-line. But this package is well-maintained and does this all under the hood and quite effectively. And it is much more flexible than `COPY` postgres command to my mind. One can filter the contents, map callbacks to fields/rows and all this on PHP side.