# Can i use a csv file as a reference for my website to which images to use?

Tags: javascript, php, html, database, csv

I have over 60 images for my website's gallery. I would like the website to read the image names from a csv file rather than writing all the code by hand. Is that possible? If yes, should I use PHP or Javascript to do that?.

Comment: _Is that possible?..._ Yes! _should I use PHP or Javascript..._ Pick the one which works fine for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to stack overflow,

You can use PHP to read the csv file. you can refer below link.

[How to parse a CSV file using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9139202/how-to-parse-a-csv-file-using-php)

Answer (score 0):

you can use python to read the csv and can use exec function to include it in php page