# Implementing a PHP counter inside of a while loop to wrap list items with ul elements

Tags: php

I am having difficulty implementing a PHP counter, to wrap my list elements in unordered list tags.

I want to wrap  around every 3 list elements.

I have been trying to use these previous questions as a guide but to little avail.

[easier way to get counter from while loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087364/easier-way-to-get-counter-from-while-loop)

[php loop counter bootstrap row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29182704/php-loop-counter-bootstrap-row)

```
            <?php

            $counter = 0; 

            echo '<ul class="products latestCourses">';

            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

            <?php $counter = $counter++; ?>

            <?php if ($counter%3 == 0) echo '</ul><ul class="products latestCourses">'; ?>

            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

This is what I have so far the page template simply contains a list element.

Currently this code is wrapping every list item in an unorder list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php $counter = $counter++; ?>
```

this line is wrong, use either

```
<?php $counter++; ?>
```

or

```
<?php $counter = $counter +1; ?>
```

Comment: ..or `$counter += 1;`

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use this for increment by 1
`$counter = $counter + 1;`

or
`$counter = $counter + n;`
where 'n' is the desired number by which you want to increment